# What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

Tags: discussion, 7-questions

Imagine you’ve just gotten on an elevator with a friendly stranger. You have precisely one floor to describe your community to them. What would you say? The elevator pitch is a brief sentence that describes *what your site is about*. Every word counts!

Once decided, it can be sliced and diced to form:

- the tagline
- the motto
- the blurb under the logo
- a convenience redirect “nickname” for the site
- perhaps eventually the domain name [in some form](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/)

(Due to a variety of [practical difficulties with domain names](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/), we prefer to de-emphasize domain name selection. Most sites will retain their `topic.stackexchange.com` names indefinitely.)

Naming is hard — *really* hard. But if you can come up with a sensible elevator pitch for your community, it’s a great starting point.

For more detail see [Stack Exchange Naming for Dummies](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/).

Comment: The Briton inside of me demands that you change the word Elevator to Lift :)

Comment: Can we compromise on "elevatour"? :)

Comment: Sure. If you're willing to pronounce tomato as /təˈmɑːtoʊ/, you've got a deal :)

Comment: Let's call the whole thing off, then.

Answer (score 4):

ELL is a community of English teaching experts and students who answer questions for one another and for English language learners. The hope is to make ELL the primary resource for English teachers and learners.

Answer (score 1):

I feel the essence of this web-page like this: People who will seek answers on their questions here most likely already learned English couple or more years. Although they are not experts they can identify that something is weird in a sentence or they can point out which words or phrases they are not certain about.

They also remember that they learned that but they (as the time goes) forgot. Most of the questions here can be answered by searching in grammar books, dictionaries or in our own notes we made during our study. The problem is that first you have to find the book (notes, dictionary, ect.) and then find the solution for your issue. That takes a lot of time (!!!).

So **ELL is all this together + you can consult with a teacher**!  I say, that is great, cool and extremely helpful!  **+ it is on-line** and often **you can see the answers from more then one teacher**. A hell of a website in deed!

So, according to me, the elevator pitch should be in this sense. I propose something like:

> Your English workbook & Your teacher - online, 24h/day!

Well, that sounds like a commercial but maybe it will help others to come up with something better :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions here:

Note They are quoted to stand out.

> 212% More effective then Google Translate

Another:

> Idioms and more from those that aren't idiots

Fun but perhaps calling people idiots is bad idea...

> English was a confusing language!

Shows we do a good job of assisting others.

Tell me what you think, and you are welcome to edit and add as you wish.